# Нужна ли запятая перед «почему»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед «почему»?

***Я нервно засмеялся, теперь зная(,) почему он все еще не принёс дитя для меня***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Придаточные предложения, входящие в деепричастный/причастный оборот, выделяются запятыми.

***Я нервно засмеялся, теперь зная, почему он все еще не принёс дитя для меня.***

Comment: Придаточное не входит в оборот. То есть не является его частью.